# Unset rows (based on row name) csv through php

Tags: php, csv

I have a .CSV file with static column names. I receive it daily so i have to automatically edit it on a daily base.

On the first line are the row names for example: row1;row2;row3,row4,row5

for example when i want to unset "row2" and "row4".

How can i unset multiple rows based on a name?

I found a some tutorials about deleting lines or rows based on a row position but nothing that helps me completely.

This is what is have now:

```
$inFile  = 'original.csv';
$outFile = 'edited.csv';

$delimiter = ';';
$enclosure = '"';   

$read = fopen($inFile, 'r');
$write = fopen($outFile, 'w');
if ($write && $read) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($read)) !== FALSE) {

        // how to unset multiple row names

        fputcsv($write, $data, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }
}
fclose($write);
fclose($read);
```

Also, do i need to use the delimiter and enclosure when i fopen the original file?

Comment: you don't delete rows from a csv. you just don't output them into a new csv file. `if (row doesn't contain what I"m deleting) { output row }`

Comment: Yes thank you, i changed everything to "unset" instead of "delete"

Comment: CSV is not a database format, and you cannot work with it the way you would a database.  You will need to write code manually to manipulate the data in string values.

Comment: More specifically, you'd need to make use of `file_get_contents()`, `file_put_contents()` ,`explode()`, `implode()`, and `if`/`then` logic, not to mention loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try the **updated** following code:

```
$inFile  = 'original.csv';
$outFile = 'edited.csv';
$delimiter = ';';
$enclosure = '"';   
$removeFields = array('color');

$write = fopen($outFile, 'w');

if ($write) {
    $rows = file($inFile);
    $first = false;
    foreach($rows as $row) {
        $csvToPHP = str_getcsv($row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
        if (!$first) {
            $headers = array_flip($csvToPHP);
            $first = true;
        }

        foreach($removeFields as $remove) {
            unset($csvToPHP[$headers[$remove]]);
        }
        fputcsv($write, $csvToPHP, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }   
}
fclose($write);
```

I used a test csv original.csv:

```
name,age,color
test1,20,red
test2,32,blue
test3,92,green
test4,12,red
test5,56,orange
```

Result edited.csv:

```
name
test1
test2
test3
test4
test5
```

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: This looks very promising but it doesn't work (yet). Could it have something to do with the delimiter and enclosure when i fopen the original file? They are not the same..

Comment: I have updated the answer. It is now using the delimiter also by reading the file.