# Change row names csv through php

Tags: php, csv

Since i am working with CSV through PHP a lot lately i have another question after asking this question about unsetting rows from a CSV through PHP: [Unset rows (based on row name) csv through php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311741/unset-rows-based-on-row-name-csv-through-php/33312277#33312277)

I have a CSV file with on the first row names: col1;col2;col3,col4,col5

How can i change the names of specific columns for example: "col1" to "Column 1", "col4" to "Column 4".

This is what i have now:

```
<?php

$inFile  = 'removed_headers.csv';
$outFile = 'final_headers.csv';
$delimiter = ';';
$enclosure = '"';   

$originals = array(0 => "RBI_Articlenr.", 1 => "Brand");
$replacements = array(0 => "sku", 1 => "manufacturer");

$write = fopen($outFile, 'w');

if ($write) {
    $rows = file($inFile);
    $first = false;
    foreach($rows as $row) {


        $csvToPHP = str_getcsv($row, $delimiter, $enclosure);
        if (!$first) {
            $headers = array_flip($csvToPHP);

            $first = true;          
        }

        $headers = array_replace($originals, $replacements);


        // now the headers array is how it should be

        // how to set the value's of $header to $csvToPHP ?


        fputcsv($write, $csvToPHP, $delimiter, $enclosure);
    }   
}
fclose($write);
```

Comment: open a file for read, and another for writing; read the first line of the file, set the column names to whatever you want and write, then loop through reading and writing in turn until end of file

Comment: @JensA.Koch Well i tried a lot of code found on stackoverflow but it was all based on inserting it to SQL and not based on saving it to a new CSV file.

Comment: @MarkBaker thats the thing, based on the link in my original question i don't know how to "set the column names to whatever you want and write". something like $columnHeadings["col1"] = "Column 1"; i guess but don't know how to really use it.

Comment: You create an array containing the names you want, and use fputcsv() to write it to file

Comment: Yes but how to change specific names.. i don't need to change all of them.

Comment: You mean you don't know how to change values in an array of data?

Comment: @MarkBaker I edited my initial question with the question in comments